# After clicking filter button values reseting

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I've created list of entries from database via HTML table via PHP. There is filters: dropdown (select options) list and text filter.

PHP looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();?>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <label for="rank">Rank applied</label>      
    <select id='english' name="RankApplied" class="test">
        <option selected disabled value="0">Select value</option>
        <option name="RankApplied" value="1">One</option>
        <option name="RankApplied" value="2">Two</option>
        <option name="RankApplied" value="3">Three</option>
    </select> 

    <label for="VesselsType">Vessel's type</label>
    <input id="VesselsType" type="text" name="VesselsType" class="etc" placeholder="Vessel's type"/>    

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
<?php
require("connect.php");
include '../../wp-load.php'; 

$RankApplied = $_POST["RankApplied"];
$VesselsType = $_POST["VesselsType"];

$UserID = get_current_user_id();

if(isset($UserID)) {    

    $users = $con->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName, 
                    RankApplied, 
                    VesselsType 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE FirstName <> '' 
          AND (RankApplied = '$RankApplied' OR '$RankApplied' = 0)
          AND (VesselsType = '$VesselsType' OR '$VesselsType' = '')
    "); 
    $users->execute();

    $users->bind_result($FName, $RankApplied, $VesselsType);


} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Rank</th>       
        <th>Vessel Type</th>
        <th>Preview</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    while ($users->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $FName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $RankApplied; ?></td>        
        <td><?php echo $VesselsType; ?></td>
        <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

If I select for example `RankApplied = 'Two'` and `VesselsType = 'FooBar'` after clicking `Filter` button It filter results correctly, but values for those fielters reseting (`RankApplied = 'Select value'` and `VesselsType = ''`), after clicking edit button It should keep/save chosen values.

Comment: Because when you hit the button it refreshes the page and everything you entered is gone

Comment: @believeme I'm looking for solution how to avoid It. Have you any ideas?

Comment: @Infinity set the `selected` attribute to the field actually selected if you know it and only set it to the first one if you don't have a previous selection. Same goes for `value=` if you have inputs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't outputting those values.  For example:

```
<input id="VesselsType" type="text" name="VesselsType" class="etc" placeholder="Vessel's type"/>
```

That just outputs an empty `input`.  Nowhere does it include the value which was posted.  You get the value here:

```
$VesselsType = $_POST["VesselsType"];
```

Just get it further up the page so you can use it in the output.  Perhaps something like this:

```
<input id="VesselsType" value="<?php=$VesselsType ?>" type="text" name="VesselsType" class="etc" placeholder="Vessel's type"/>
```

The same concept applies for the `select`, but is slightly more involved.  In that case you'd check if the value equals what was posted and set the `selected` attribute on an `option` element.  There are a number of ways to do it, and my PHP is *very* rusty, but something like this might do the trick:

```
<option <?php echo isset($_POST["RankApplied"]) ? "" : "selected"; ?> disabled value="0">Select value</option>
<option <?php echo $RankApplied == "1" ? "selected" : ""; ?> name="RankApplied" value="1">One</option>
etc...
```

However you do it, the point remains the same.  You need to output those values to the page in order for those values to be on the page.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but in this case `RankApplied` always have 1 value (One) and `VesselsType` still blank. Also `VesselsType` a little bit corrected instead of `value="<?php=$VesselsType ?>" ` used `value="<?php echo $VesselsType; ?>"`

Comment: @Infinity: When that happens, what were the values that were posted?  Are you getting them above that part of the page where you use them?  If `$VesselsType` is empty then it seems to follow that `$_POST["VesselsType"]` was empty.

Comment: But if `$VesselsType` would be empty so `SQL query` wouldn't worked too, isn't it? I mean `$VesselsType` is used in `SQL query's WHERE clause` and It working, filtering results correctly.

Comment: @Infinity: I don't know what specifically you changed, so the problem could literally be anything.  You may have to do some debugging to find out where it's failing.

Comment: Just tried to `echo $VesselsType;` and It returning entered value correctly.

Comment: Input looks like: `<input id="VesselsType" type="text" name="VesselsType" value="<?php echo $VesselsType; ?>" class="test" placeholder="Vessel's type"/>`

Comment: @Infinity: So the problem is solved then?  Because if `echo $VesselsType;` returns the correct value, then it would logically follow that `echo $VesselsType;` would also return the correct value.

Comment: I dont know why, but after clicking `Filter` button It filtering results correctly, but text field became blank again. Also options -> select after clicking `Filter` button always get value selected = 1.

Comment: Option > select looks like: `<select id='english' name="RankApplied" class="test">
  <option <?php echo isset($_POST["RankApplied"]) ? "" : "selected"; ?> disabled value="0">Select rank</option>
  <option <?php echo $RankApplied == "1" ? "selected" : ""; ?> name="RankApplied" value="1">One</option>
  <option <?php echo $RankApplied == "2" ? "selected" : ""; ?> name="RankApplied" value="2">Two</option>`

Comment: @Infinity: Clearly you're doing *something* wrong here.  Because if `echo $VesselsType;` both *does* **and** *does not* return the correct value, then you've broken something.  I can't know what because I can't see your code.  Somehow you're modifying the value of that variable between the two times that you use it.

Comment: Found issue, I've used php code below html form... Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score -1):

You can save values with SESSION['rank'] and SESSION['type'] for example and display them when it's filtered.

When user sets the filter and hits the button give those values to session variables and display them.